# Checking logs of scheduler in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g, scheduler

I need a query for checking the logs of all the jobs successfully executed or failed scheduled using the scheduler package.

Answer (score 1):

A simple select for the logs would be:

`select * from all_scheduler_job_log`

This manual is also worthy:

`http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse002.htm#CHDGIDFD`

Make sure you have the logs properly configured:

`http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2047.htm#i1587038`

Additional reading:

`http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2047.htm#i1587038`

Those documents links to all relevant stuff imho-